# No presets visible in pulseaudio-equalizer

Tags: 18.04, sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio

I've installed `pulseaudio` through the ubuntu repo, ie;

```
sudo apt install pulseaudio*
```

then following Arch Linux wiki's instructions appended the following lines:

```
### Load the integrated PulseAudio equalizer and D-Bus module
load-module module-dbus-protocol
load-module module-equalizer-sink
```

in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

- I ran `qpaeq` in terminal to open the `pulseaudio-equalizer` (GUI) which showed that no presets were saved (no defaults at all).
- I tried saving a custom preset (raised one particular frequency from normal & clicked on the floppy icon to save it) & then tried to use locate & find the preset by name but that ended in no results found, i opened the `qpaeq` again to check if it was there & it was.

[Screenshot of the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2fSW.png)

The `flat` preset was named by me, originally there wasn't a name. No other preset is present.

I wish to either restore the presets somehow or manually write & store those presets at the location it checks for these presets. The question is how to do that?